# Fastest way to create an index of an unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am working on a problem where I have an unsorted array. And I need to process this array in order to generate an index array as if it were sorted in an ascending order.

Example 1:

let's say I have an unsorted array [9, 7, 8, 6, 12]

And as an output, I need an index array [3, 1, 2, 0, 4].

Example 2:

Unsorted array :        [10, 9, 11, 8, 12]
Index array should be : [ 2, 1,  3, 0, 4]

As of now, I am doing it just like old "bubble sort" where I'm comparing each and every possibility. I was wondering way to make it fast.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It can go upto 10 ^ 5. I'm not worried about extra space at the moment ? I am looking for ways to optimize it to make it faster.

Comment: `[2, 1, 3, 0, 4]` looks incorrect, because it corresponds to `[11, 9, 8, 10, 12]`, which is not an ascending order.

Comment: Sort the indices (they start as 0 to size-1) according to the values in the array. A bottom up merge sort would be slightly quicker than a quick/heap sort, since it typically has fewer compares and more moves. The compares involve referencing both an index and an array value, while the moves only involve the indices.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think there is a misunderstanding about my question. What I need is index of an unsorted array as if they were sorted in ascending order. In 2nd example, unsorted array is [10, 9, 11, 8, 12] so, if you sort it in ascending order it would be [8, 9,10, 11, 12] and hence index with reference to unsorted array would be [2, 1, 3, 0, 4]. ie, position of 10 is 2nd in an ascending order. 9 is 1st and etc. Is it clear ? I think it's still a lil confusing.

Comment: @dastaan I see. Funny how the output was the same for your first example! I edited to explain how to get this output from the array you get after sorting pairs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Perfect. :) I reached the same solution after enumerating it for a couple of more examples. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not worried about extra space, do this:

1. Make an array of pairs `(value, index)`
2. Sort pairs on the value (first member) in ascending order
3. Harvest indexes (second member) from the sorted array of pairs

Using your data as an example, you would get this:

```
[{9,0}, {7,1}, {8,2}, {6,3}, {12,4}] // Step 1
[{6,3}, {7,1}, {8,2}, {9,0}, {12,4}] // Step 2
[   3,     1,     2,     0,      4 ] // Step 3
```

> (comment) I need is index of an unsorted array as if they were sorted in ascending order.

You can use array from step 3 to produce this output as well. Using your second example, you get this:

```
[{10,0},  {9,1}, {11,2},  {8,3}, {12,4}]
[ {8,3},  {9,1}, {10,0}, {11,2}, {12,4}]
[    3,      1,      0,      2,      4 ]
```

Now create the output array, walk the array of indexes (i.e. `[3,1,0,2,4]`) and set the index of each item into the position in the result determined by the value, i.e. index 3 would get 0 because 3 is at index 0, index 1 would get 1 because 1 is at 1, index 0 would get 2 because 0 is at 2, and so on.

Here is the illustration of that additional step:

```
int position[] = {3, 1, 0, 2, 4};
int res[5];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    res[position[i]] = i;
}
```

This produces the following array:

```
[2, 1, 3, 0, 4]
```

Comment: Got it. So basically i need to pick up an optimized sorting algorithm to make it faster. (compared to bubble sort which is O(n^2), may be merge sort or quick sort.)

Comment: I think this method doesn't always give accurate result. Take [{10,0},{9,1},{11,2},{8,3},{12,4}] for example. By this method it gives order as [3,1,0,2,4] while actual order is : [2,1,3,0,4]. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @dastaan Why would the correct order be  [2,1,3,0,4]? This would mean that [11, 9, 8, 10, 11] is the proper order, but the proper order is [8, 9, 10, 11, 11].

Comment: Had a typo. Corrected my comment. If you sort [{10,0},{9,1},{11,2},{8,3},{12,4}] on its value, wouldn't it be [{8,3},{9,1},{10,0},{11,2},{12,4}]. Upon harvesting indexes, I will get [3, 1, 0, 2, 4]. But actual index order should be [2, 1, 3, 0, 4]. (unsorted array is : [10,9,11,8,12])

Answer (score 1):

"Fast" means you need a sorted data structure with an complexity of O(log n) for *inserts* (and lookups of course). So a binary tree would do.

Comment: You need to insert n objects, so that's O(n log n), and binary tree operations would take more time than an O(n log n) sort such as a merge sort. If sorting indices in C++, then std::stable_sort() which normally uses merge sort would be a bit faster than std::sort(), which is an intro sort, a quick sort that switches to heap sort if the nesting gets too deep.

Answer (score 1):

You create the index as an array of positions, and initialize it to the existing order:  idx=[0, 1, 2, ...., n-1].
Then you sort the index array using your favorite sorting algorithm, but whenever performing a comparison, you use the values as positions to refernce the original array, instead of comparing them directly. For example, to compare the items i and j, you perform  cmp(arr[idx[i]], arr[idx[j]])   instead of cmp(idx[i], idx[j]).

Comment: 3 instructions in python:    arr=[9, 7, 8, 6, 12]    idx=[i for i in range(len(arr))]       idx.sort(lambda i, j: cmp(arr[i], arr[j]))

Comment: This answer is basically the same as the answer from "dasblinkenlight", it's just better because it doesn't require all the redundant steps of his answer, such as allocating extra space, copying the values, and dicarding them in the end (why bother doing those things when you can compare using referenced positions to the original array?)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Radix Sort:

```
* Approach:
 *   radix sort, like counting sort and bucket sort, is an integer based
 *   algorithm (i.e. the values of the input array are assumed to be
 *   integers). Hence radix sort is among the fastest sorting algorithms
 *   around, in theory. The particular distinction for radix sort is that it
 *   creates a bucket for each cipher (i.e. digit); as such, similar to
 *   bucket sort, each bucket in radix sort must be a growable list that may
 *   admit different keys.

 ***************************************************************************/
import java.io.IOException;


public class RadixSort {

    public static void sort( int[] a)
    {
        int i, m = a[0], exp = 1, n = a.length;
        int[] b = new int[10];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (a[i] > m)
                m = a[i];
        while (m / exp > 0)
        {
            int[] bucket = new int[10];

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                bucket[(a[i] / exp) % 10]++;
            for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1];
            for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                b[--bucket[(a[i] / exp) % 10]] = a[i];
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                a[i] = b[i];
            exp *= 10;        
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int[] aa={9,7,8,6,12};
        for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(aa[i]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        sort(aa);
        for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(aa[i]+"  ");
        }
    }


}
```